# MySQL did not use index in SUM with GROUP BY query

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing, sum, query-optimization

I just created a table with:

```
CREATE TABLE `table_test` (
`time` date NOT NULL,
`line_id` char(36) NOT NULL,
`location_id` char(36) NOT NULL,
`placement_id` char(36) NOT NULL,
`flight_id` char(36) NOT NULL,
`impressions` int(11) DEFAULT `0`,
PRIMARY KEY (`time`,`line_id`,`location_id`,`placement_id`,`flight_id`),
KEY `table_test_IDX` (`time`,`placement_id`,`line_id`,`impressions`) USING 
BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Then when I try to execute a query:

```
SELECT 
  time,
  placement_id,
  line_id,
  SUM(impressions) AS totalImpress
FROM
  table_test
WHERE
  time BETWEEN '2017-11-01' AND '2017-11-30'
GROUP BY time , placement_id , line_id;
```

It always uses `Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort`, in this case, I want the query uses `table_test_IDX`.

What did I do wrong here?

Many thank.

Answer (score 0):

If you peruse the MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-optimization.html) for optimization of aggregation queries, you will find that there are two methods to optimize a `GROUP BY` query, namely loose and tight index scans.  However, one caveat for either of these scans is that the only aggregate functions used in the select list are `MIN` or `MAX`.  Because you are selecting a `SUM`, these optimizations are not available.

It makes sense to use an index which can benefit your `WHERE` clause, because that might let us discard records from the result set early on in the query plan.  However, in order to compute a sum for each group, MySQL has to touch each record in the remaining table.  There is no way around this in order to get a sum, so it does not really matter how we access all these records.

Comment: Thank Tim for your answer. But I wonder when I try to run the query with this option: `USE INDEX(table_test_IDX)`. The query's time faster 2x than normal.

Comment: Yes, but at which point in the query is that index being used?  The optimizer does not always get things right.  If you have a fairly small data set, with reasonable running times, I wouldn't over analyze things; most of the time, the optimizer is smarter than you.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are using UUIDs?  Change `CHAR(36)` to `CHAR(36) CHARACTER SET ascii`.  Better would be to pack them into `BINARY(16).  (See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uuid .)  This shrinks the size from 108 to 36 to 16.

You say it is using filesort, etc, but is it using `PRIMARY`?  Please provide the `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.

But, to get even more speed up, consider building and maintaining "Summary table(s)".  (See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables .)  If you had one row in a summary table per combo of (time , placement_id , line_id), the `GROUP BY` and `SUM` could be removed.  (If you summarize by hour, you would still need those.)